How can I simulate the Jackal UGV in Unity or Unreal Engine with ROS2 integration?
I am trying to simulate the Jackal UGV (from Clearpath Robotics) in a photorealistic environment using either Unity or Unreal Engine. My goal is to integrate this simulation with ROS2 (Humble on Ubuntu 22.04) to control the UGV and simulate all sensor streams (e.g., LiDAR, cameras, IMUs).
The official Jackal repository provides URDF files and sensor configurations, but I am unsure how to import these into Unity or Unreal Engine for simulation. Specifically, I am looking for help with the following:

How can I import the Jackal UGV model (URDF and sensor configurations) from the repository into Unity or Unreal Engine?
What tools or plugins (e.g., ROS–TCP Connector for Unity, ROS2 Bridge for Unreal) should I use to simulate all the sensor streams (e.g., LiDAR, cameras, IMUs) in either engine?
Are there any tutorials or resources that demonstrate how to set up a ROS2 simulation for the Jackal UGV in Unity or Unreal Engine?
Which engine (Unity or Unreal) is better suited for simulating a ROS2-compatible ground vehicle with sensor streams in a photorealistic environment?

